# pytest using custom markers and codecov coverage

Tags: pytest, code-coverage, pytest-markers

I am  using pytest for testing different functions and classes in my application. I would like to make use of the custom markers in pytest to mark specific tests with either unit, integrated or system depending on the test like so:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.unit
def test_example_1():
   pass

@pytest.mark.integrated
def test_example_2():
   pass

@pytest.mark.system
def test_example_3():
   pass
```

I understand it is possible to to run pytest with the specific markers using:

```
pytest test.py -m unit
```

And I can get the coverage using `--cov-report xml --cov-report term`,  but I was wondering if there was a way to create separate coverage files for each marker.

And also on a more general note, is there a way to check all the tests collected to ensure they have a marker and what it is?